# Array is empty, relation one to many, cakephp

Tags: cakephp

```
print_r($products);
```

**Returns:**

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 )
```

**...is wrong. It have to be **

```
[1] => product_item_1, 
[2] => product_item_2, ....etc.....
```

Why array is wrong?

**KlientsController.php:**

```
class KlientsController extends AppController {
     var $name = 'Klients';
     var $scaffold;

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Form');
public $components = array('Session');

  public function newedit($id = null) {
      $this->Klient->recursive = 1;
      $this->loadModel('Product');
      $products=$this->Product->find('list',
                array('Product.id','Product.product_name'));
```

Klient.php (model):

```
   `class Klient extends AppModel {
       var $name = 'Klient';
        var $belongsTo = array('Product');

 function newedit($id = null){    
        $products = $this->Klient->Product->generateList();       
        $this->set('products', $products);

}
```

**newedit.ctp:**

```
 echo $this->Form->input('product_id', 
                 array('options' => $products));
```

This drop down list contains 13 items, that's correct, but it is empty....why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  don't see the field

```
$products=$this->Product->find('list',
              array('fields' => array('Product.id','Product.product_name')));
```

Comment: In /view/
     `echo $this->Form->input('product_id',  
                array('options' => $products));`

$product have correct number or records, it is 13. The number is row has products table. But shows only 1 => 1, and etc.

I have added to KlientController.php this:

    `var $uses = array ('Klient', 'Product');`

But nothing happend better.

Comment: I have found solution.